# Firebase Storage: The operation 'getDownloadURL' cannot be performed on a root reference, create a non-root reference using child, .child('file.png')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to get the url of image from firebase storage in my react app, but I am getting this error. code is working fine on localhost but giving error whenever I deploy it .

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Home from '../../Components/organisms/Home/Home';
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL} from "firebase/storage";

import {
  loginUserInfoSelector,
  userLoginObjectSelector,
} from "../../Redux/Login/selectors";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const loginUserData = useSelector(loginUserInfoSelector);
  const [profileurl, setprofileurl] = useState('')


  const storage = getStorage();
  const fileRef = ref(storage, loginUserData?.profileUrl);

  getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((URL) => {
    console.log(URL)
    setprofileurl(URL)

  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });


  return (
    <div>
    <Home newprofile={profileurl} />
     </div>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `loginUserData?.profileUrl` is not returning a value, likely because `loginUserData` is null.

You'll probably only want to try and load the profile picture when the `loginUserData` is not null, and maybe even route to a different screen when there is no signed in user..